# Getting error while executing the ./build_native.sh from Cocos2d-x Android-Project

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm getting error while executing the android-project created on Cocos2d-x, The error is:

```
$ ./build_native.sh
NDK_ROOT = D:\Updated Eclipse\android-ndk-r10
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/Cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/projects/MyApp/proj.android/../../..
APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/Cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/projects/MyApp/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/Cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/projects/MyApp/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
ERROR: You are using a non-Cygwin compatible Make program.
Currently using: D:/Cocos2d-X/Cygwin/bin/make

To solve the issue, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that the Cygwin 'make' package is installed.
   NOTE: You will need GNU Make 3.81 or later!

2. Define the GNUMAKE environment variable to point to it, as in:

     export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make

3. Call 'ndk-build' again.
```

I have installed all the required SW and set the path, environment etc properly,

**Cocos2d-x version:** Cocos2d-x-2.2.5

**Android ADT:** Latest Android SDK

**Android NDK:** android-ndk-r10

**Cygwin:** 32-bit

**Cygwin package installed** autoconf, automake, binutils, gcc-core, gcc-g**, gcc4-core, gcc4-g**, gdb, pcre, pcre-devel, gawk, make

**Python:** python-2.7.8.msi

The Path and environment are:

**ANDROID_NDK_PATH** C:\Users\d\Documents\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r8d

**COCOS2DX_ROOT** D:\Cocos2d-X\cocos2d-x-2.2.5

**GNUMAKE** /usr/bin/make

**NDK_PROJECT_PATH** D:\Cocos2d-X\cocos2d-x-2.2.5\projects

**NDK_ROOT** D:\Updated Eclipse\android-ndk-r10

**Path** D:\Cocos2d-X\Cygwin\bin

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NDK is in a folder "Updated Eclipse". You need to rename your folder such that it does not have any space. After renaming, update your NDK path in "build_native.sh" and then try rebuilding.